# How do I install Facebook's Buck Build onto an existing Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook, buck

I am having trouble trouble installing Buck with an existing Xcode project. I was able to successfully get it working with the sample project though. When I try to do it with my project I get a variety of errors such as `Error: Could not find or load main class com.facebook.buck.cli.bootstrapper.ClassLoaderBootstrapper`. What are some step by step instructions on how to add it successfully?

Comment: Are you trying to build with Buck itself, or just generate your Xcode project?

Comment: I am trying to build it with Buck itself

Answer (score 1):

To generate an XCode project from Buck build files use:

```
buck project --ide xcode
```

See [the documentation](https://buckbuild.com/command/project.html) for more information.

If you want to build with Buck, then you need to create the appropriate Buck targets in your `BUCK` files. For example:

```
apple_binary(
  name = 'MyBinary',
  deps = [
    ':MyLibrary',
    '//Libraries:AnotherLibrary',
  ],
  preprocessor_flags = ['-fobjc-arc'],
  headers = [
    'MyHeader.h',
  ],
  srcs = [
    'MySource.m',
  ],
  frameworks = [
    '$SDKROOT/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework',
    '$SDKROOT/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework',
  ],
)
```

There are more [examples on the Buck website](https://buckbuild.com/rule/apple_binary.html).

As far as I know, there is no automated way to create Buck files from an Xcode project; you can only go the other way. Writing a Buck file is very easy though, and perhaps a good opportunity to tidy up your project.

Once you have written your `BUCK` files, you can build using:

```
buck build :MyBinary
```